# How to UPDATE along with INSERT INTO SELECT

Tags: mysql, update, insert

I added some entries from `table2` to `table1` as

```
INSERT INTO table1 (title) SELECT title from table2 WHERE ...
```

how can I UPDATE `table2` for the `SELECT`ed or `INSERT`ed entries as

```
UPDATE table2 SET status='Used'
```

Comment: 1) `INSERT .. VALUES SELECT ..` not exists. Either `INSERT .. VALUES ..` or `INSERT .. SELECT ..`. 2) One query cannot have both INSERT and UPDATE type - so you need at least 2 queries. But I recommend 3-step way - mark for insert, insert, update marked. 3) Does `table1.title` have unique constraint?

Comment: Your question is not clear, please try to improve it by adding some sample data and the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure, what you are after. There is no automated way to do this. You could of course write a trigger, but that would execute for every insert that happens on table1, which is most likely not what you want.

Usually you would just put your statements in a transaction and put a lock on the to be updated rows. Like this:

```
start transaction;
insert into table1(title) select title from table2 where foo=bar for update;
update table2 set status= 'Used' where foo=bar;
commit;
```

Comment: I think the condition looks like `WHERE foo = bar AND status != 'Used'` ...

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. This will only work if you have PRIMARY KEY (title) on table1.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (title)
SELECT title FROM table2 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE status = 'Used'
```

The statement `INSERT`s rows on table1 unless the new row would cause a duplicate primary key, in that case it does an `UPDATE` on the `status` column.

Comment: Sorry, this is wrong. The update in this statement works on the table which is inserted into, in this case table1. You want to update table2, though.

Comment: My bad, you are right. Your answer is the correct one. For completeness sake I would only check that the isolation level is repeatable read (which is the default). Maybe it would be a good idea to add `set session transaction isolation level REPEATABLE READ;` before starting the transaction.